# Convert dataframe to dictionary with arrays

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a Pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob'],
    'age': [25, 30, 35],
    'city': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago']
})
}
```

which produces output

```
       name     age     city
0   John    25  New York
1   Alice   30  Los Angeles
2   Bob 35  Chicago
```

I  need to convert the dataframe to below format using `df.to_dict()`

```
{
    'name': ['John', 'Alice', 'Bob'],
    'age': [25, 30, 35],
    'city': ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'Chicago']
}
```

The output I am getting with `df.to_dict()  is

```
{'name': {0: 'John', 1: 'Alice', 2: 'Bob'},
 'age': {0: 25, 1: 30, 2: 35},
 'city': {0: 'New York', 1: 'Los Angeles', 2: 'Chicago'}}
```

I have checked the pandas [documentaion](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)  which does not have example which is as per my requirements.

**Note:** I can loop over the above output and get  desired output bit I wanted to know if I can do it directly using pandas bult in functions

Comment: `df.to_dict(orient='list')`